# Make gives an error when trying to build lua

Tags: c, windows, makefile, lua

I am trying to make Lua so I can use it but it always spits out the same error and I'm following the official site.

```
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/name/lua-5.4.4/src'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '`uname`'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/name/lua-5.4.4/src'
make: *** [Makefile:99: guess] Error 2
```

Thanks,
Will

Comment: What environment are you using? MSYS, mingw, cygwin? uname is a Linux system utility, so this makefile seems to assume it can run that (or a configuration step put “`uname`” in there instead of the output of uname. Do the Lua makefiles support Windows or is a separate Visual Studio solution provided?

Comment: The documentation included with the source describes the steps necessary for building on non-Unix-like platforms. If you are on a Unix-like platform, you need to figure out how to install a package that provides `uname`.

Comment: Alternatively, run the command `make PLATFORM`, where `PLATFORM` is one of the platforms in the `Makefile`, which includes `linux`, `macosx`, and `mingw`. This is described if you run `make help`. In the above comment, Unix-like includes `mingw`.

Comment: I am on windows.

Comment: @Lolz Are you in a Unix-like environment like MSYS2, mingw, cygwin, etc? Where is the `make` you're using coming from?